# How to properly store the value throughout the recursion?

Tags: python

I have been solving leetcode questions and encountered a problem. For some of the questions about binary trees, it is necessary to record the longest path. Usaually, I do something like this:

```
class Solution:
    def traverse(self,cur):
        if not cur:
            return -1
        l = self.traverse(cur.left)
        r = self.traverse(cur.right)
        l += 1
        r += 1
        self.ans = max(self.ans,l+r)
        return max(l,r)
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        self.ans = 0
        cur = root
        self.traverse(cur)
        return self.ans
```

I try to initialize a **variable(self.ans)** which can be remembered during the whole recursion, and it can be updated whenever I need to. I have not seen this kind of implementation and wonder if it is a big NO in coding interview. By the way, it is leetcode 543 if anyone wants to know.

Comment: That's not really the way recursive solutions work in general. Usually you propagate the solution using the `return` of the recursive function. Like you process the current element, then recurse to handle the rest. This tends to look something like `return ans + fun(rest_of_the_values)`

Comment: it seems strange in `diameterOfBinaryTree ` to call `self.traverse(cur)` and have it set `self.ans` and then `return self.ans`... why not write it in such a way that you can `return self.traverse(cur)` instead

Comment: Often, recursive functions are part of a 'pure' functional programming style, in which functions consistently return the same values given the same arguments and have no side effects. These would typically be standalone functions rather than part of a class (which leetcode requires for some reason). Pure functions have some advantages such as being easier to unit test and debug. A recursive function that manipulates an external variable may become particularly confusing to reason about (which 'branch' of the recursion has changed it most recently?) So best avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, that there's a specific best practice, so it all comes down to one's preferences and a problem specific. Take your problem for example. You can write code in different way (following code snippets are bodies of `diameterOfBinaryTree` method).

You can store distances in the list and pass it to every call (somewhat similar to *backtracking*)

```
dists = []

def max_dist(node, dists):
    left_depth = max_dist(node.left, dists) if node.left else 0
    right_depth = max_dist(node.right, dists) if node.right else 0
    
    dists.append(left_depth + right_depth + 1)
    
    return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1

max_dist(root, dists)

return max(dists) - 1
```

You can define variable in the outter scope and store result there

```
mmax = 0

def max_dist(node):
    nonlocal mmax
    left_depth = max_dist(node.left) if node.left else 0
    right_depth = max_dist(node.right) if node.right else 0
    
    mmax = max(left_depth + right_depth + 1, mmax)
    
    return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1

max_dist(root)

return mmax - 1
```

Or you can accumulate and return result on each call

```
def max_dist(node):
    left_depth, left_max = max_dist(node.left) if node.left else (0, 0)
    right_depth, right_max = max_dist(node.right) if node.right else (0, 0)
    
    mmax = max(left_max, right_max, left_depth + right_depth + 1)
    
    return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1, mmax

_, mmax = max_dist(root)
return mmax - 1
```

So, I think you should write code that suits your vision of the problem. Especially on the interview, where your main goal is to solve a problem and write *working* and *bugless* code.